# MySQL will not accept INSERT INTO table with varchar, tinytext, time, time values

Tags: php, html, mysql

MySQL gives an error when I try to input data into the following table my_table:

```
my_table
Columns | data type:
Task    | varchar(20) (primary key)
Descr   | tinytext
start   | time
end     | time
```

The my_table character set is utf8

I am trying to insert values into the table from a PHP file:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "passwd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("my_table") or die(mysql_error());

$task = $_POST["taskname"];
$descr = $_POST["taskdesc"];
$start = $_POST["starttime"];
$end = $_POST["endtime"];

$insert = "INSERT INTO tasks (task, descr, start, end) 
VALUES ('$task','$descr','$start','$end')";

mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

?>
```

I receive the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'descr, start, end) VALUES ('Task 1','This is a task. This is only a task. This ' at line 1

Here is the html that gives the inputs:

```
<form id="taskentry" method="post" action="create-task.php">
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="taskname" placeholder="Task Name"/></li>
    <li><textarea form="taskentry" name="taskdesc" placeholder="Description" rows="5"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="time" name="starttime"></li>
    <li><input type="time" name="endtime"></li>
    <li class="naked"><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Submit Task" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I suspect it is a format issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way. You should switch away from the deprecated `mysql_` set of functions to PDO or MySQLi and use parametrized queries, which might even solve the problem, too, apart from making sure just anyone can't drop all your tables or something.

Comment: Incidentally, did you put a single quote (`'`) inside your test description?

Comment: "You're vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way." – minitech"

Thanks. I'm a noob, but you should tell this to w3schools.com because that's where I picked up this bad code.

Comment: In the example code I posted here I used 'descr' as a column name, but in my actual code I used 'desc', which is a MySQL reserved word - hence the error.

Comment: Ah, well, w3schools has a history of being terrible and not responding to requests for improvement. See: http://w3fools.com/. And congrats on solving it! =)

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the references they suggest instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to insert data using mysql comand prompt, if that works then try to check if your form data is submitted to your action php page or not. you can write a code to test that

```
if(isset($_POST["taskname"]) && isset($_POST["taskdesc"]) && isset($_POST["starttime"]) && isset($_POST["endtime"]))
{
$task = $_POST["taskname"];
$descr = $_POST["taskdesc"];
$start = $_POST["starttime"];
$end = $_POST["endtime"];
echo $task."<br />".$descr."<br />".$start."<br />".$end;
}
```

Comment: In the example code I posted here I used 'descr' as a column name, but in my actual code I used 'desc', which is a MySQL reserved word - hence the error.